# How do i send a file with sockets in python?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, mp3, send

I am already familiar with python and socket usage and can send strings of text over these. But how would i go about sending, say, an MP3 file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would do what you literally ask (assuming `thesocket` is a connected stream socket):

```
with open('thefile.mp3', 'rb') as f:
    thesocket.sendall(f.read())
```

but of course it's unlikely to be much use without some higher-level protocol to help the counterpart know how much data it's going to receive, what type of data, and so forth.

Comment: You probably want to split that up so that not the whole file is read into memory at once.

Comment: @Jake, consider accepting the answer (by clicking on the checkmark-shaped icon to the left of the answer) -- accepting the answer to you question that has most helped yoi is crucial SO etiquette (and as such is rewarded by giving you a few extra rep points, and a few more to me;-).

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the tip. I am quite new here :)